# Reference a interface from a controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, interface

I am using an interface to handle different payment options.

The thing is in my controller I get the bank slug but based on that slug I decide which class Bank in my case to use to process the payment. My controller:

```
public function sendPayment($request, PayBank $bank_transacton)
{

    here I want to reference the SentToBank interface and
   send payment class that I get in return from checkBankImplementation function//

    SendToBank()->sendLoanApplication($bank_transaction);
}
```

method to check for the slug so I know which payment service to sent to the interface:

```
public static function checkBankImplementation($bank_slug) {

    switch ($bank_slug) {

    case "firstbank":
        return new app\FirstBank\Client();
        break;

    case "secondbank":
        return new app\SecondBank\Client();
        break;
    default:

        return null;
    }
}
```

my interface :

```
<?php

namespace App\Banks;

interface SendToBank {

    public function sendLoanApplication($bank_transaction);

}
```

Comment: What classes implement the SendToBank interface?

Comment: Two other classes each represents a bank  that they have the same method sendLoanApplication($bank_transaction)

Comment: If you want to reference an interface rather than an implementation, you will need to [bind implementation to an interface](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations). But I'm not sure that makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 1):

1- your `app\FirstBank\Client()` and `app\SecondBank\Client()` needs to implement the `SendToBank` interface.

2- From your controller, you have to create the proper object using your static method.

3- Call the `sendLoanApplication` method on that object

Something like that:

```
public function sendPayment($request, PayBank $bank_transacton)
{

    $bankClient = Class::checkBankImplementation($bank_slug); // You need to change the class name with the one actually implementing the checkBandImplementation method and extract the proper $bank_slug from the request

    $bankClient->sendLoanApplication($bank_transaction);
}
```

Comment: No. checkBankImplementation is a static method so you just need the class name for calling it, without creating a new object with `new`. In which class you actually implemented that method?

Comment: We need to know the name of the classes where you implemented the methods you posted above